Writing responsive css inside an html file
im trying to create a small bit of text with an image to the right of it. However, the site im working on doesnt have the option to create a stylesheet so i have to write my css inside of my html file. The code below shows what im working on (the image is just a random one):


<div style="display:flex; max-width:980px; margin:auto; align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
  <div style="padding: 10px;">
    <h1 style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 2em; padding-bottom: 25px;">Title</h1>
    <p style="width: 30vw;">paragraph of text.
    
    another paragraph of text</p>

  </div>
  <img style="padding: 10px; width:100px;" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5e10bdc20efb8f0d169f85f9/09943d85-b8c7-4d64-af31-1a27d1b76698/arrow.png" />

</div>



Is there a way to make it so that when the text and the image dont fit next to eachother anymore, the image gets put underneath the text?

How about a <style> tag at the start of your HTML code? It works like a stylesheet (i.e. listing the css rules, media queries etc.), but right there in the file.

use tailwindCss

flex-wrap: wrap;


<style>
  .d1 {
    display:flex;
    max-width:980px;
    margin:auto;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;          /* NEW */
  }
  .d1 > :first-child {
    padding: 10px
  }
  .d1 h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .d1 p {
    width: 30vw;
  }
  .d1 img {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>paragraph of text.</p>
    <p>another paragraph of text.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5e10bdc20efb8f0d169f85f9/09943d85-b8c7-4d64-af31-1a27d1b76698/arrow.png" />
</div>



